# Why does stdout redirection work with puts but not write?

Tags: c, unix, io-redirection

If I use `puts`, I can redirect stdout as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *s = "hello world";
    puts(s);    
    return 0;
}
```

Redirecting it:

```
$ gcc -Wall use_puts.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ ./a.out > /dev/null
```

However, if I use `write` to write to stdout, shell redirection has no effect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char *s = "hello world\n";
    write(0, s, strlen(s));
    return 0;
}
```

Redirecting it:

```
$ gcc -Wall use_puts.c
$ ./a.out
hello world
$ ./a.out > /dev/null
hello world
```

Why is this? How can I redirect writes to stdout in this case?

Comment: If you are under Linux and had used `strace ./.a.out` with the `puts()` version, you would have found out that `puts()` calls `write()` with file descriptor 1, not 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `write` statement is writing to *stdin* rather than *stdout*. I'm surprised it works at all.

This is generally why you should use constants rather than literal values, because it's less prone to this sort of error:

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, s, strlen(s));
```

(`STDOUT_FILENO`, `STDIN_FILENO`, and `STDERR_FILENO` are defined in `unistd.h`)

Comment: It works because no redirection was done, and he's running from a terminal, so stdin, stdout, and stderr are all going to the terminal - and the terminal was probably opened read/write, so you could write to any of them (and read from any of them).  ***NOT*** something to rely on; the code needs to be fixed to write to stdout.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that *stdin* would normally be restricted to read-only. Color me surprised.

Comment: That's a natural assumption, but I guess the login procedure/terminal-emulator startup procedure on many UN\*Xes just does one open of the tty rather than the two that would be needed to prevent writing to stdin or reading from stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 3):

You write into stdin, I think you want this

```
write(1, s, strlen(s));
```